# IronPython calling method with params : dynamically invoking correct method with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, ironpython, parameters

I am using C# as my host lang and my proxy is IronPython and I am setting methods inside of my scope pragmatically. So, my tenitive problem is my proxy method for calling the proper method via refection. the parameters are `string methodName` and `params object[] args` the code content of the method is:

```
initalScope.Add(obj.Name.ToLower(), new Func<object[], dynamic>( param 
                    => ReflectionMethodProxy( obj.Name ,  param ) ));
```

this was my initial setup. My problem with this is that when i attempt to pass one parameter in ironpython, i get the error `expected Array[object], got str` which is understandable, However, it should take 1 parameter since the parameter for the method calls for `params`.

so i changed the method call to this

```
initalScope.Add(obj.Name.ToLower(), new Func<object, dynamic>( param 
                    => ReflectionMethodProxy( obj.Name , param.GetType() != typeof (Array) ? new [] { param } : param ) ));
```

which works for one parameter, but obviously would not work for multiple parameters.
my goal is to be able to pass multiple parameters via Ironpython and then distribute the to the correct method in c#. Below is my code. Im probably missing something obvious, but ive been at it for a while now and really need some more eyes.

the outcome of the test code below is two errors
`methodcall("test1")` - *provides expected* `Array[object] got str` error
`methodcall("test1",3)` - *provides* `Invoke() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

```
// dummy method for format sake
public void setScope()
{
    foreach (var obj in LinkedDocument.GetType().GetMethods().Where(
             method => method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ScriptingVoidAttribute), true).Length != 0 
             || method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ScriptingFuncAttribute), true).Length != 0))

            initalScope.Add(obj.Name.ToLower(), new Func<object[], dynamic>( param 
                => ReflectionMethodProxy( obj.Name , param ) ));
}

public dynamic ReflectionMethodProxy( string methodName , params object[] args )
{
     return LinkedDocument.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, args.Select(obj 
                => obj.GetType()).ToArray())
            .Invoke(LinkedDocument, args);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? IronPython does all of this to call methods already; there's no need to duplicate it.

Comment: Yes, correct me if i am wrong, but if i want to call methods that are contained in a class and didn't want to access them via class hierarchy, I would have to add them to the scope with the key as there name. Right? On assumption that this is the case, i am adding them because i donot want to access them from my class object. So to optimize i would like to utilize `params object[]`

Comment: @JeffHardy if you have advice on how to achieve my goal with out causing code redundancies, please advise.

Comment: To finish the comment above the one above this... "and not have to have a switch statment base on the number of parameters a method has."